# C# GUI hangs when i try to connect using socket. need a way to separate GUI Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, user-interface

I need a way to separate GUI thread when i try to connect sockets
My C# code connects properly without any hang in GUI when the lan cable to connected to the port of PC when my APP is running. no issue there.
But when there is no Lan port connected to the PC  where my APP is trying to connect, Ideal behavior i am expecting is that the APP waits for a Socket connection and the GUI doesn't freeze.
I tried using threads like `TaskFactory.StartNew Method (Action)`
But i see that it successfully resolves GUI hang but doesn't connect to the lan `sometimes`
below code is my latest attempt to solve this issue but found it no good.

```
    try
   {

                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,ports);

                        clientSocket = default(TcpClient);

                        int counter = 0;

                        serverSocket.Start();

                        counter += 1;

                        dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>

                        {

                            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

                        }));

                        MessageBox.Show(ports + " " + "Connected!");


                    } 

     catch (Exception w) 
                    { 
                        MessageBox.Show(ports + " " + "Connection error!"); 
                    }
```

Help needed: When No lan port is connected to the PC, and when the APP tries to connect to that port, instead of GUI hang it must wait gracefully.

Comment: Using async work item is a good idea. You probably need to try Task.Run instead of TaskFactory.StartNew because of some default settings of scheduler may make your work item not to be executed immediately.

Comment: Hi bob, I am currently running on  VS 2010  client 4 profile

Comment: alright, let me try something with your info :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        var ports = 1234;
        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            var serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, ports);

            var clientSocket = default(TcpClient);

            int counter = 0;

            serverSocket.Start();

            counter += 1;
            var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                    MessageBox.Show(ports + " " + "Connected!");
                }
            }, source.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
        }
        catch (Exception w)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ports + " " + "Connection error!");
        }
```

Comment: its not working man. it connects sometimes. and also how do i check or ignore if socket is already connected?

Comment: @anilgadiyar, the line after `clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();` is the place where you check if socket is already connected. If you want multiple connections, place the code of `AcceptTcpClient` in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Async` or `Begin` method (depending if your environment supports async/await or not).

Due to the fact that you *only* have VS2010 you should use [the `Begin` approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient.aspx):

```
private void InitializeListiner()
{
    var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, ports);
    listener.Start();
    listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnClientConnected, listener);
}

private void OnClientConnected(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    var listener = (TcpListener)asyncResult.AsyncState;
    var client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyncResult);
    listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnClientConnected, listener);

    // ToDo: send and receive data from/to client...
}
```

Comment: Hi oliver the  above method can be used for multiple client sockets ? if so what changes has to been done ?

Comment: This listener already supports multiple clients, cause it calls the `.Begin()` method again within the `OnClientConnected()` method. Within the todo comment you could e.g. store the client in an array to access it from other methods that want to broadcast some information to all connected clients.

Comment: how Can i specify a handle to each socket connected or a  different thread in your code?

Comment: The received `client` is a `TcpClient`, which has all needed methods and properties to send and receive data.

Comment: its not working man. it connects sometimes. and also how do i check or ignore if socket is already connected?